# Нужно написать функцию с новым массивом

Tags: java, функции, методы

Напишите функцию, которая принимает массив целых чисел a и два числа start и end. Возвращает новый массив элементы с индекса start (включительно) до индекса end (не включительно).

Вот мое решение, не уверена. что верное и еще,  не могу написать вывод нового массива. Помогите пожалуйста! )

```
public static int copy (int [] a, int start, int end){
        int lenArr = end - start;
        int [] arr = new int[lenArr];
        for (int i = 0; i < lenArr; i++){
            arr[i] = a[start + i];
        }
        return arr[lenArr];
    }
```

---

Вот мой вывод:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8};
        int start = 2;
        int end = 5;
        System.out.println(copy(a, start, end));
    }
```

Comment: "Возвращает новый массив" --- `arr[lenArr]` - это не массив

Comment: Вам нужно только возвращать массив, а не объект массива. Остальное вроде норм.

Comment: Если я пишу только: return arr  идея подчеркивает красным и пишет ошибку: Required type:
int Provided: int[] Вот поэтому и пишу длину

Comment: Предполагаю. что ошибка в самой функции - перечитываю который раз, не понимаю, вроде на существование имеет место быть, но почему тогда выдает ошибку при возврате массива.

Comment: Правильно подчёркивает.....ведь там возвращаемый тип стоит int а не массив

Comment: Да все верно, спасибо. Исправила. Но сейчас вывод неверный

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8};
        int start = 2;
        int end = 5;
        System.out.println(copy(a, start, end));
    }

Comment: Вот таку ошибку пишет: Implicit call to 'toString()' on array returned by call to 'copy(a, start, end)' - перевод Неявный вызов 'toString()' для массива, возвращаемого вызовом 'copy(a, start, end)'

Comment: скорее всего ты пытаешься его писать в system.out.print........ но для вывода элементов поотдельности - придётся делать цикл

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[] copy (int [] a, int start, int end){ //возвращаем массив, а не
                                                         //просто int, как у вас.
        int lenArr = end - start;
        int [] arr = new int[lenArr];
        int index = 0; //заводим счетчик результирующего массива arr
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++){ //Пробегаем циклом по требуемым элементам входящего массива в диапазоне [start - end) 
            arr[index] = a[i]; // копируем каждый элемент в новый массив.
            index++;
        }
        return arr; // при возврате размер не указываем. Он уже указан при инициализации. 
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8};
        int start = 2;
        int end = 5;
        print(copy(a, start, end)); //для вывода элементов поочередно создадим отдельный метод print
}
public static void print(int arr[]){
    for (int i : arr){
     System.out.print (i + " ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно возвращать массив чисел, тогда нужно поменять возвращаемое значение на int[].